# Gaps and islands: client solution vs T-SQL query

Tags: sql-server, performance, gaps-and-islands, query-performance

Can a T-SQL solution for gaps and islands run faster than a C# solution running on the client?

To be specific, let us provide some test data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Numbers
  (
    n INT NOT NULL
          PRIMARY KEY
  ) ; 
GO 

INSERT  INTO dbo.Numbers
        ( n )
VALUES  ( 1 ) ; 
GO 
DECLARE @i INT ; 
SET @i = 0 ; 
WHILE @i < 21 
  BEGIN 
    INSERT  INTO dbo.Numbers
            ( n 
            )
            SELECT  n + POWER(2, @i)
            FROM    dbo.Numbers ; 
    SET @i = @i + 1 ; 
  END ;  
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Tasks
  (
    StartedAt SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL ,
    FinishedAt SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL ,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Tasks PRIMARY KEY ( StartedAt, FinishedAt ) ,
    CONSTRAINT UNQ_Tasks UNIQUE ( FinishedAt, StartedAt )
  ) ;
GO

INSERT  INTO dbo.Tasks
        ( StartedAt ,
          FinishedAt
        )
        SELECT  DATEADD(MINUTE, n, '20100101') AS StartedAt ,
                DATEADD(MINUTE, n + 2, '20100101') AS FinishedAt
        FROM    dbo.Numbers
        WHERE   ( n < 500000
                  OR n > 500005
                )
GO
```

This first set of test data has exactly one gap:

```
SELECT  StartedAt ,
        FinishedAt
FROM    dbo.Tasks
WHERE   StartedAt BETWEEN DATEADD(MINUTE, 499999, '20100101')
                  AND     DATEADD(MINUTE, 500006, '20100101')
```

The second set of test data has 2M -1 gaps, a gap between each two adjacent intervals:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.Tasks;
GO

INSERT  INTO dbo.Tasks
        ( StartedAt ,
          FinishedAt
        )
        SELECT  DATEADD(MINUTE, 3*n, '20100101') AS StartedAt ,
                DATEADD(MINUTE, 3*n + 2, '20100101') AS FinishedAt
        FROM    dbo.Numbers
        WHERE   ( n < 500000
                  OR n > 500005
                )
GO
```

Currently I am running 2008 R2, but 2012 solutions are very welcome.
I have posted my C# solution as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

The following C# code solves the problem:

```
    var connString =
        "Initial Catalog=MyDb;Data Source=MyServer;Integrated Security=SSPI;Application Name=Benchmarks;";

    var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        var command = conn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "dbo.GetAllTaskEvents";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        var gaps = new List<string>();
        using (var dr = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var currentEvents = 0;
            var gapStart = new DateTime();
            var gapStarted = false;
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                var change = dr.GetInt32(1);
                if (change == -1 && currentEvents == 1)
                {
                    gapStart = dr.GetDateTime(0);
                    gapStarted = true;
                }
                else if (change == 1 && currentEvents == 0 && gapStarted)
                {
                    gaps.Add(string.Format("({0},{1})", gapStart, dr.GetDateTime(0)));
                    gapStarted = false;
                }
                currentEvents += change;
            }
        }
        File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Temp\Gaps.txt", gaps);
    }

    stopWatch.Stop();
    System.Console.WriteLine("Elapsed: " + stopWatch.Elapsed);
```

This code invokes this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetAllTaskEvents
AS 
  BEGIN ;
    SELECT  EventTime ,
            Change
    FROM    ( SELECT  StartedAt AS EventTime ,
                      1 AS Change
              FROM    dbo.Tasks
              UNION ALL
              SELECT  FinishedAt AS EventTime ,
                      -1 AS Change
              FROM    dbo.Tasks
            ) AS TaskEvents
    ORDER BY EventTime, Change DESC ;
  END ;
GO
```

It finds and prints one gap in 2M intervals in the following times, warm cache:

```
1 gap: Elapsed: 00:00:01.4852029 00:00:01.4444307 00:00:01.4644152
```

It finds and prints 2M-1 gaps in 2M intervals in the following times, warm cache:

```
2M-1 gaps Elapsed: 00:00:08.8576637 00:00:08.9123053 00:00:09.0372344 00:00:08.8545477
```

This is a very simple solution - it took me 10 minutes to develop. A recent college graduate can come up with it. On the database side, execution plan is a trivial merge join which uses very little CPU and memory.

**Edit:** to be realistic, I am running client and server on separate boxes.

Comment: Yes, but what if I want the resultset back as a dataset, not as a file?

Comment: Most applications want to use IEnumerable<SomeClassOrStruct> - in this case we just yield return instead adding a line to a list. To keep this example short, I have removed lots of things not essential to measuring raw performance.

Comment: And that is free of cpu? Or does it add time to your solution?

Comment: @PeterLarsson can you suggest a better way to benchmark? Writing to a file mimics quite slow consumption of data by the client.

Answer (score 4):

And a 1 second solution...

```
;WITH cteSource(StartedAt, FinishedAt)
AS (
    SELECT      s.StartedAt,
            e.FinishedAt
    FROM        (
                SELECT  StartedAt,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StartedAt) AS rn
                FROM    dbo.Tasks
            ) AS s
    INNER JOIN  (
                SELECT  FinishedAt,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FinishedAt) + 1 AS rn
                FROM    dbo.Tasks
            ) AS e ON e.rn = s.rn
    WHERE       s.StartedAt > e.FinishedAt

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  MIN(StartedAt),
        MAX(FinishedAt)
    FROM    dbo.Tasks
), cteGrouped(theTime, grp)
AS (
    SELECT  u.theTime,
        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY u.theTime) - 1) / 2
    FROM    cteSource AS s
    UNPIVOT (
            theTime
            FOR theColumn IN (s.StartedAt, s.FinishedAt)
        ) AS u
)
SELECT      MIN(theTime),
        MAX(theTime)
FROM        cteGrouped
GROUP BY    grp
ORDER BY    grp
```

Comment: This is about 30% faster than your other solution. 1 gap: (00:00:12.1355011 00:00:11.6406581), 2M-1 gaps (00:00:12.4526817 00:00:11.7442217). Still this is about 25% slower than the client side solution in its worst case, exactly as predicted by Adam Machanic on twitter.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution which runs in 4 seconds.

```
WITH cteRaw(ts, type, e, s)
AS (
    SELECT  StartedAt,
        1 AS type,
        NULL,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StartedAt)
    FROM    dbo.Tasks

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  FinishedAt,
        -1 AS type, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FinishedAt),
        NULL
    FROM    dbo.Tasks
), cteCombined(ts, e, s, se)
AS (
    SELECT  ts,
        e,
        s,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ts, type DESC)
    FROM    cteRaw
), cteFiltered(ts, grpnum)
AS (
    SELECT  ts, 
        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ts) - 1) / 2 AS grpnum
    FROM    cteCombined
    WHERE   COALESCE(s + s - se - 1, se - e - e) = 0
)
SELECT      MIN(ts) AS starttime,
        MAX(ts) AS endtime
FROM        cteFiltered
GROUP BY    grpnum;
```

Comment: Peter, on a data set with one gap this is more than 10 times slower: (00:00:18.1016745
-- 00:00:17.8190959)

On the data with 2M-1 gaps, it is 2 times slower: (00:00:17.2409640 00:00:17.6068879)

Answer (score 3):

I think I have exhausted the limits of my knowledge in SQL server on this one....

For finding a gap in SQL server (what the C# code does), and you don't care about starting or ending gaps (those before the first start, or after the last finish), then the following query (or variants) is the fastest I could find:

```
SELECT e.FinishedAt as GapStart, s.StartedAt as GapEnd
FROM 
(
    SELECT StartedAt, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StartedAt) AS rn
    FROM dbo.Tasks
) AS s
INNER JOIN  
(
    SELECT  FinishedAt, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FinishedAt) + 1 AS rn
    FROM    dbo.Tasks
) AS e ON e.rn = s.rn and s.StartedAt > e.FinishedAt
```

Which works though slight of hand that for each start-finish set, you can treat the start and finish as separate sequences, offset the finish by one and gaps are shown.

eg take (S1, F1), (S2, F2), (S3, F3), and order as: {S1, S2, S3, null} and {null, F1, F2, F3}
Then compare row n to row n in each set, and gaps are where the F set value is less than the S set value... the problem I think is that in SQL server there is no way to join or compare two separate sets purely on the order of the values in the set... hence the use of the row_number function to allow us to merge based purely on row number... but there is no way to tell SQL server that these values are unique (without inserting them into a table var with an index on it - which takes longer - I tried it), so I think the merge join is less than optimal? (though hard to prove when it's faster than anything else I could do)

I was able to get solutions using the LAG/LEAD functions:

```
select * from
(
    SELECT top (100) percent StartedAt, FinishedAt, LEAD(StartedAt, 1, null) OVER (Order by FinishedAt) as NextStart
    FROM dbo.Tasks
) as x
where NextStart > FinishedAt
```

(which by the way, I don't guarantee the results - it seems to work, but I think relies on StartedAt being in order in the Tasks table... and it was slower)

Using sum change:

```
select * from
(
    SELECT EventTime, Change, SUM(Change) OVER (ORDER BY EventTime, Change desc ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as RunTotal --, x.*
    FROM    
    ( 
        SELECT StartedAt AS EventTime, 1 AS Change
        FROM dbo.Tasks
    UNION ALL
        SELECT  FinishedAt AS EventTime, -1 AS Change
        FROM dbo.Tasks
    ) AS TaskEvents
) as x
where x.RunTotal = 0 or (x.RunTotal = 1 and x.Change = 1)
ORDER BY EventTime, Change DESC
```

(no surprise, also slower)

I even tried a CLR aggregate function (to replace the sum - it was slower than sum and relied on row_number() to keep the order of the data), and CLR a table valued function (to open two result sets and compare values based purely on sequence)... and it too was slower.  I banged my head so many times on SQL, and CLR limitations, trying many other methods...

And for what?

Running on the same machine, and spitting both the C# data, and SQL filtered data into a file (as per original C# code), the times are virtually the same.... approximately 2 seconds for the 1 gap data (C# usually faster), 8-10 seconds for the multi-gap data set (SQL usually faster).

**NOTE**: Do not use the SQL Server Development Environment for timing comparison, as it's display to grid takes time.  As tested with SQL 2012, VS2010, .net 4.0 Client profile

I will point out that both solutions perform pretty much the same sorting of data on the SQL server so the server load for fetch-sort will be similar, whichever solution you use, the only difference being the processing on the client (rather than server), and the transfer over the network.

I don't know what the difference might be when partitioning by different staff members perhaps, or when you might need extra data with the gap information (though I can't think of much else other than a staff id), or of course if there is a **slow** data connection between the SQL server and client machine (or a **slow** client)...  Nor have I made a comparison of lock-times, or contention issues, or CPU/NETWORK issues for multiple users... So I don't know which one is more likely to be a bottleneck in this case.

What I do know, is yes, SQL server is not good at this sort of set comparisons, and if you don't write the query right you will pay for it dearly.

Is it easier or harder than writing the C# version?  I'm not entirely sure, the Change +/-1, running total solution is not entirely intuitive either, and I but it's not the first solution an average graduate would come to... once done it is easy enough to copy, but it takes insight to write in the first place... same can be said for the SQL version.
Which is harder?  Which is more robust to rogue data?  Which has more potential for parallel operations?  Does it really matter when the difference is so small compared to the programming effort?

One last note; there is an unstated constraint on the data - the StartedAt **must** be less than the FinishedAt, or you will get bad results.